# Could i change later my registration information as an Instagram Developer

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to check how Instagram API workds.
I started registration and stuck on filling my information step.
Could i change later my registration information as an Instagram Developer 
https://monosnap.com/file/IGF5ZpgQ22TM0Wr5gkSFR0PsnWyQDA
They ask to fill information as Company Name, WebSite URL and so on. I dont have this inf now. I just check how their API works. So could i change this inf later?
thank you.

Comment: Maybe. Why not create the account and find out... It's free isn't it?

Comment: Or, you know, ask Instagram?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an Instagram developer account and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact Instagram regarding questions about your account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and once your application is approved, you have some flexibility to change:

- Application Name
- Description
- Company Name
- Website URL
- Privacy Policy URL
- Contact email
- Valid redirect URIs

Just remember, Instagram is very strict. If you're asking this because you're trying to skirt the API Policies, then the answer is, Yes but your Client will lose it's permissions. Just stay in compliance when you make changes or risk being banned. It's really not worth working against Instagram.

Comment: Mike, what docs do they ask to verify "Company Name"? Do they ask for incorporation papers or DBA doc is fine? I'm not sure if Instagram is on the same level as Apple's...